# Get Current Selected Checkbox value using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to get current selected value from selected check box from table.Below the code i am using for get selected value from checkbox.But It is getting all the selected value from table.I need only selected table row value.

```js
$.each($('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').closest("td").next("td"), function() {
  values.push($(this).text().trim())

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DeviceTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th style="width: 10px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check_selectall-custom" onclick="selectAllCustom(this)" />SA</th>

      <th>Device</th>
      <th> Type</th>
      <th> Model</th>
      <th> Status</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="parameter_table">

    <tr id="tr_device_id1">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" onclick="DeviceClickedBox()">
      </td>

      <td id="macadd" style="word-break:break-all;">
        Mac1
      </td>

      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Dev 1
      </td>
      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Model 1
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
        <b id="Selected_Device" style="float: right;"></b>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_device_id2">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]" onclick="DeviceClickedBox()">
      </td>

      <td id="macadd" style="word-break:break-all;">
        Mac 2
      </td>

      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Parm 2
      </td>
      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Model 2
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
        <b id="Selected_Device" style="float: right;"></b>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please add your HTML to the question

Comment: We'll need your HTML to fix your problem.

Comment: added html.erb also.

Comment: I made you a snippet. HTML, not template is needed to have a [mcve] Please add relevant script. Like the functions you have `selectAllCustom` and `DeviceClickedBox`

Comment: I can't look at the code, it hurts. 1. Use a *.css file, dont do inline styles 2. Use names for your "name" attribute, not "[]" or other such things 3. ids and classes should be in lowercase 4. functions should also be lowercase

Comment: You have duplicate IDs - not that it is a problem with the code you have, but it is not recommended

Comment: Do you have multiple such tables? And when your code will be executed, on any button click or what?

Comment: no.When i click check box i need to get selected checkbox value

Answer (score 0):

Give your TDs a class instead of ID

I do not know what you want to click, but here I do it on click of the checkbox

```js
$(function() { // assuming jquery is loaded, execute on page load
  $("#check_selectall-custom").on("click", function() {
    var checked = this.checked;
    $("input[type=checkbox]").not(this).prop("checked",checked);
  });
  $("#getval").on("click", function() {
    var values = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").not(this).map(function() {
      return $(this).closest("tr").find(".macadd").text().trim();
    }).get();
    $("#res").html(values.join("<br/>"))
  });
});
```

```css
#tr_device_id1 td {
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DeviceTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th style="width: 10px;">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="check_selectall-custom" />SA</label>
      </th>

      <th>Device</th>
      <th> Type</th>
      <th> Model</th>
      <th> Status</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="parameter_table">

    <tr id="tr_device_id1">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]">
      </td>

      <td class="macadd">
        Mac 1
      </td>

      <td class="device">
        Dev 1
      </td>
      <td class="model">
        Model 1
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_device_id2">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkBox[]">
      </td>

      <td class="macadd">
        Mac 2
      </td>

      <td class="device">
        Dev 2
      </td>
      <td class="model">
        Model 2
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="getval">Show checked</button>
<span id="res"></span>
```

Comment: Thanks.I am getting Uncaught TypeError: $(...).on is not a function.

Comment: I am using this way but doesn't return any values

Comment: $("#check_selectall-custom").click(function ()  {
            var values = $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").not(this).map(function() {
              return $(this).closest("tr").find(".macadd").text().trim();
            }).get();
            alert(values)
          });

Comment: i have added id='check_selectall-custom' in html

Comment: what is the use of not(this) here

Comment: I took all checkboxes including the check all

Comment: did i make any mistake?

Comment: Obviously. You post too little info for me to help. Update your question

Answer (score -2):

```js
var TotalChkBx;

$("input:checkbox").on("click", function() {
  var n = $("input:checkbox").index(this);
  $('#detail').append("Column 1" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody  tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(1) ").text() + '<br/>');
  $('#detail').append("Column 2" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(2) ").text() + '<br/>');
  $('#detail').append("Column 3" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody  tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(3) ").text() + '<br/>');
  $('#detail').append("Column 4" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(4) ").text() + '<br/>');
});


function CheckAll(CheckBox) {
  $('#detail').html("");
  var TargetBaseControl = document.getElementById("DeviceTable"); // objRef.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
  var TargetChildControl = "check";
  //var Check_TEXT = "CHECK_CheckBox"

  var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("input");
  // var Spans = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName("span");
  for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n) {
    if ((Inputs[n].type === 'checkbox')) // 
    {
      Inputs[n].Checked = CheckBox.checked;
      $("#" + Inputs[n].id).attr("Checked", CheckBox.checked);

      $('#detail').append("Column 1" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody  tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(1) ").text() + '<br/>');
      $('#detail').append("Column 2" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(2) ").text() + '<br/>');
      $('#detail').append("Column 3" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody  tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(3) ").text() + '<br/>');
      $('#detail').append("Column 4" + $("table#DeviceTable tbody tr:eq(" + n + ") td:eq(4) ").text() + '<br/>');
    }
    //  else { $('#detail').html("");}

  }
  Counter = CheckBox.checked ? TotalChkBx : 0;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="DeviceTable" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr class="info">
      <th style="width: 10px;">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="checkBox" id="check_selectall-custom" onclick="CheckAll(this)" />SA</th>

      <th>Device</th>
      <th> Type</th>
      <th> Model</th>
      <th> Status</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="parameter_table">

    <tr id="tr_device_id1">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="checkBox">
      </td>

      <td id="macadd" style="word-break:break-all;">
        Mac1
      </td>

      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Dev 1
      </td>
      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Model 1
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
        <b id="Selected_Device" style="float: right;"></b>

      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_device_id2">
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="checkBox">
      </td>

      <td id="macadd" style="word-break:break-all;">
        Mac 2
      </td>

      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Parm 2
      </td>
      <td style="word-break:break-all;">
        Model 2
      </td>
      <td class="Selected_Device" id="Selected_Device">
        <b id="Selected_Device" style="float: right;"></b>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="detail"></div>
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do? OP did not ask for all that extra code